# How do I view form code history?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a C# desktop application for a class, using Visual Studio Online source control system. It gave me a choice of Team Foundational Server or Git, and I choose Git because I've heard of it and my professor recommends it. This is my first time using these features and I'm finding them a little confusing.

I can view the history of most of the files I'm working with, and revert to old versions, but I can't seem to do that for my form code. I think it has to do with what files are attached to source control, indicated by the blue lock icons.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqkvB.png]

I would like to be able to see the history of Production Buddy.cs, what am I doing wrong here? I can see Production Buddy.Designer.cs's history, so I may be not fully understanding what's going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, strangest thing. I added a new form, and noticed it was included in source control. So I made a new commit, sync'd with the server, and then I could view it's history. Then I deleted the new form, and noticed a red check mark next to Production Buddy.cs. I made another commit, and sync'd, and now Production Buddy.cs has a blue padlock and I can view history.

So I think I got what I was looking for, I just don't understand why what I did worked.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows there was neither red tick or blue tick. Which indicates that the file was not under source control. This happened may be because you copy pasted the file or the solution was on offline mode or solution file was updated when you took latest which replaced the entry of `Production Buddy.cs` file, and since it was not on the server there was no server history for that file.

I would recommend using [Source Control Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181370.aspx) when you have to compare the files.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. As for Source Control Explorer, it says I can't use it unless my Source Control plug-in is Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, instead of Microsoft Git Provider, which it currently is. When I set the project up, I choose to use Git over VSTFS, so can I use the other plug-in? I'll admit to not really know the pros and cons of either, much less if the plug-ins are inter-operable.